# Codeigniter Registration Form: After registering a user it redirects to a blank page

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, redirect

I'm trying to register a user to the system here. I have 'Registration' controller, 'RegistrationModel' model, and the 'registration' view.
When I register a user giving details after clicking the register button user should be redirected back to the registration page then a message need to be displayed to ask the user to check his/her email. (I have used a Gmail SMTP) but when I register the user all the data is saved to the database but user is not redirected to the registration page URL goes to validation.

Registration.php Controller

```
public function validation(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[pizzanow_registration.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confirm Password','required|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){

        $verificationkey = md5(rand());
        //$encryptedpassword = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('password'));
        $data = array(
            'fname' =>$this->input->post('fname'),
            'lname' =>$this->input->post('lname'),
            'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
            'password' =>$this->input->post('password'),
            'verificationkey' =>$verificationkey
        );
        $id = $this->registrationmodel->insert($data);
        if ($id > 0){

            //Sending and asking to verify Email of registering user
            $subject = "Please verify your email for login.";

            //The message that user will view in their email
            $message = "<p>Hi".
                        $this->input->post('fname')
                        ."</p>
                        <p>
                        This is your email verification mail from the PizzaNow!
                        For Complete registration process please login into our website.
                        But first let's verify your email by clicking on the below link,
                        </p>
                        <a href=".base_url()."registration/verifyemail/".$verificationkey.">verify email</a>
                        <p>Once you click the above link your email will be verified and you will be able to login to the system.</p>
                        <p>Thanks,</p>";
            //Configuring SMTP setting for sending emails
            $config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host'=> 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                //can also try with 587
                'smtp_port' => '587',
                'smtp_timeout'=>'7',
                'smtp_user'=>'<Gmail email address>',
                'smtp_pass'=>'xxxxxx',
                'charset'=>'utf-8',
                'newline'=>"\r\n",
                'mail_type'=>'html',
                'validation'=>TRUE
                );
            //initialize the configuration

            $this->load->library('email',$config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('<Gmail email address>','PizzaNow');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);


            $this->load->helper('url');
            if ($this->email->send()){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Please check in you inbox to verify you email.');
                redirect_back();
                echo "Email sent successfully";
            }else{
                redirect('/registration','refresh');
                echo "Login Failed";
                $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

RegistrationModel.php

```
public function insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('pizzanow_registration',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function verifyemail($key){
    $this->db->where('verificationKey',$key);
    $this->db->where('isEmailVerified','no');
    $query = $this->db->get('pizzanow_registration');
    if ($query->num_rows()>0){
        $data = array(
            'isEmailVerified'=>'yes'
        );
        $this->db->where('verificationKey',$key);
        $this->db->update('pizzanow_registration',$data);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

registration.php view

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>registration/validation">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <?php
                                if($this->session->flashdata('message')){
                                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata("message").'</div>';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('fname');?>"/>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <?php
                                    echo form_error('fname');
                                    ?>
                                </span>
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('lname');?>"/>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <?php
                                    echo form_error('lname');
                                    ?>
                                </span>
                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>"/>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <?php
                                    echo form_error('email');
                                    ?>
                                </span>
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>"/>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <?php
                                    echo form_error('password');
                                    ?>
                                </span>
                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('cpassword');?>"/>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <?php
                                    echo form_error('cpassword');
                                    ?>
                                </span><br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-info"/>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: what happens if you comment/disable this one ```redirect_back()```? btw, remove your sensitive information e.g. your email password.

Comment: **!CAUTION! You have published your password. It is now public and compromised. Change your password right-now!** For more information, see: [security credentials (e.g. usernames, passwords, etc.), etc. should be treated as compromised. All such items which are security concerns should be invalidated and changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/7939871)